# JSF: throw 404 error if GET parameter is omitted

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I need to throw 404 error, if invalid GET parameter is passed to page. I've attached it to validator as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4902757/1973599). But if there is no parameter at all, validator is not being invoked. How can I handle this situation?

Comment: In the validate method (in the post linked by you), you can still find out if the parameter received is `null` and still redirect. Did you try this?

Comment: Yes, I tried. As I said, validate method is invoked only if parameter is received. I think, URL should look like `/page.jsf?param=` to pass `null` to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place exactly the same check you're doing now with the validator, but inside a listener associated to the `preRenderView` event:

```
<f:event listener="#{yourBean.validateParams}" type="preRenderView"/>
```

This `validateParams` listener should have a check like this one:

```
public void validateParams() {
    if (yourParam == null || /*Other fitting conditions here*/) {
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        facesContext.getExternalContext().responseSendError(404, "The param 'yourParam' is missing");
        facesContext.responseComplete();
    }
    //Other params here
}
```

This approach works for multiple parameters, where you can validate each one of them and act accordingly.